# How to use labeller with facet wrap to generate unique facet labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

Consider this example if I wanted each facet to be labelled with the first 11 letters of the alphabet? rather than the value of gear then carb.

```r
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = disp))+
  facet_wrap(gear~carb, labeller = c(LETTERS[1:11]))
```

I can't use facet_grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved like so:

`labels` is a data.frame with two cols `gear` and `carb` where each row corresponds to one combination of the two vars. The labeller should return a list or dataframe, e.g. when using a list the first element if the first line of the label, the second element the second line ...

Hence to label the facets with letters we just have to return a list with one element, i.e. the first `nrow(labels)` elements of `LETTERS`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars)+
  geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = disp))+
  facet_wrap(gear~carb, labeller = function(labels) list(LETTERS[1:nrow(labels)]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, out of interest. Is it possible to expand the answer to how you would match the labels to specific combinations of the variables. i.e. if  1st facet was to be labelled B, the second one E, without editing the positions in the list?

Comment: I just added some explanatory comments. In principle you can do whatever transformations you like in the function, e.g. reverse the vector via rev or draw a sample or ...